# Access the Jquery element from within ready

Tags: jquery

So I want to call some jQuery for each element with a class of "blah" when the document has loaded

In the function I call, i need to access inner html of the "blah"P object - however passing the function `this` just seems to send some sort of global document object.

What can I do to resolve this?

Apparently people want code to visualise what I'm assuming is pretty trivial.

Here:

```
$(".blah").ready(function(){callThisFn(this);};

...

function callThisFunction(fnThis){
   var x = $(fnThis).find("thisExists");
   alert(JSON.stringify(x)); // undefined
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". Certainly after 5+ years on Stack Overflow you know we require at least some code in a question like this?

Comment: Providing code would likely help solve this problem moreso than the explanation of said problem would. (both would be even better)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery the elements are accessed using id's and classes. Use this code snippet to help you:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.blah').html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(var i = 0; i<$('p.blah').length; i++){
    console.log($('p.blah').eq(i).html());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p class="blah">aaa</p>
  <p class="blah">bbbb</p>
</div>
```